# JS Object/Element Selector tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, orchardcms

I need a to build a web tool that is able to select elements in a page and get details such as ID, classes and data attributes, similar to how Firefox Firebug, Chrome Inspector or JQuery Shape Tracing in Orchard works like below:

**Chrome Inspector**

[image: Chrome Inspector]

**Orchard JQuery Shape Tracing**

[image: Orchard JQuery Shape Tracing]

[Selector Gadget](http://www.selectorgadget.com/) looks promising but I was hoping for alternatives. I'd prefer something that plainly gets element IDs, classes and attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean like `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: not familiar with that but i need all elements in a page to be selectable. when the mouse cursor hovers on an element it is highlighted. when clicked, element attributes are returned (ID, class, data-attribs).

Comment: Yeah then that's what you need. You can start here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web. Try implementing your own code, then if you got problems come back with the code you got so far, explain why it didn't work, what other options you tried, and if possible provide a live demo.

Comment: thanks @elclanrs! this is pure JS right? I need to build a tool that is not browser-specific.

Comment: AnimaSola, @stackoverflow, we try to improve upon your code. Let us have a look at what you have tried till now, so we can build upon it.